# talend etl toracleOut error

Tags: talend

I am a newbie to TalendETL and am using Talend Open Studio for Big Data version 6.2. I have developed a simple Talend ETL job that picks up data from a *tOracleInput* and inserts data into my local Oracle Database. Below is how my package looks:

The job returns an exception that in component tOracleOutput_1

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32703
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2677)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9270)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:210)
    at bmtprojet.faitsuivicmpgn_0_1.FaitSuiviCmpgn.tOracleInput_1Process(FaitSuiviCmpgn.java:1903)
    at bmtprojet.faitsuivicmpgn_0_1.FaitSuiviCmpgn.runJobInTOS(FaitSuiviCmpgn.java:2278)
    at bmtprojet.faitsuivicmpgn_0_1.FaitSuiviCmpgn.main(FaitSuiviCmpgn.java:2135)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is used by the driver. It is known as error BUG-6396242 (see [Readme for Driver 11.1.0.7.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/111070-readme-083278.html)).

Happens if the batch is too big. So either set the batch smaller in the tOracleOutput component or try a different mode for inserting the data.

The driver is usually tied very deeply into Talend, so it is complicated to update it.